# SharePoint 2013 on-premise Yammer feed auto login

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, yammer

I have a SharePoint 2013 on-premise portal and I have used content editor webpart to inset Yammer embed script. I have also added the following urls to IE trusted sites.

```
https://*.assets-yammer.com
https://*.yammer.com
```

When I load the page it displays the yammer webpart with a login button and when I click on the login button it does the auth and the webpart displays feed.

If I have Yammer opened in another browser tab then the webpart automatically loads the yammer feeds (using the auth info).

What should I do to auto login and display the feeds when the webpart loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution on Yammer developer site... Hope this helps someone.

https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/single-sign-on

```
    yam.connect.embedFeed({
  container: '#embedded-feed'
        , feedType: ''
        , feedId: ''
        , config: {
             use_sso: true // this line enables SSO
             , header: true
             , footer: true
             , showOpenGraphPreview: false
             , defaultGroupId: 3257958      // specify default group id to post to 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately Yammer SSO is deprecated and hasn't worked since December 1, 2016.